# Two professors won't respond to grade issues -- No credit for work which would have raised my grades to an A. What GPA to write on CV/Resume?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, cv, grades

The past two semesters these professors in some non-rigorous courses back to back have disregarded my communications regarding a grading error they or their TA's have made. One was an attendance/class activity they didn't see my reminder for in a canvas comment and the other was some ridiculous kangaroo court assessment by a TA, where 1 point on an essay of 3 I had earned which was not considered(a paper on media bias in elections had a rubric which suggested to discuss the slant of fox vs. cnn vs. msnbc etc. in the recent elections -- It wasn't clear and assumed this was for the recent primary election and not the general election, and they docked me 10%.) Both classes had 3.0 credit hours and gave me a A-.

How would you handle it? Would you accept this for what it was, keep (respectfully) harassing them, or go about other means?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a rant rather than a question

Comment: "a paper on media bias in elections had a rubric which suggested to discuss the slant of fox vs. cnn vs. msnbc etc. in the recent elections -- It wasn't clear and assumed this was for the recent primary election and not the general election" I am just a passer-by, but if you wrote something that is not understood, it means it was not so clearly written and therefore it deserves a "lower than maximum" score.
If you feel you are worth more than your academic ratings, catch up with professional work/experience, show the world you can do things on par with people with a GPA 4+

Comment: To answer the question in the title: of course you need to put the GPA you actually have, not the GPA you think you deserve, on your CV.

Comment: Fraud in an application can/will result in summary rejection.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the U.S., your University likely has a formal mechanism for grade appeals. If you have already reached out multiple times, you should find out how to appeal the grade and use this process. I was the chair of the review committee for a time at my university, and true grading mistakes were often resolved in the students' favor.

That said, it is not clear to me if the second item you bring up is a mistake vs. a professor who didn't think you completed the assignment in a way that was up to standard. I think the burden of proof will be higher in this case.

Until you have completed this process, the GPA you should write on the application is the one that is on your transcript.

Final point: An A- is still an A, and will likely not affect your graduate school application in a substantial way.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help